# Selectively cut down numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy float array "data" of shape (7890, 7)

The data is just a set of numbers, 7 columns and 7890 rows.

I'm trying to create a new array:

```
reference = np.empty((0,7),dtype=np.float)
```

then iterate over my data array, and insert into the empty array based on a condition like so:

```
    for num1, num2, num3, *dummy in data:
        indices = num2 < 20
        reference = data[indices]
```

This keeps returning an array size for reference of:

(1, 7890, 7)

Any idea how I can do this? I'm trying to strip the data array down by condition num2 < 20.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think you need a for loop. `reference = data[data[:,1] < 20]` -

Comment: I see what you did there, but how could I get that into a new array? reference = data[data[:,1] > 20] ?

Comment: I believe that did it, makes sense. No idea why I was thinking this needed a for loop.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be cutting the array down at all? Should reference still be the same size as data ?

Comment: Never mind, stupid mistake on my part. Works perfectly.

Comment: When you assign one array to `reference`, and later assign another (in the loop) you don't change the original array.  You just change what `reference` references.  Also the idea of `inserting into an empty array` doesn't work with `numpy` arrays.  You can only concatenate arrays to make a new array - and you shouldn't do that in a loop (it's much less efficient than appending to a list).